# What is the best way to ignore undefined values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm building a project with Vue.js using Vuex. I am getting data from an API, which is a content-management system. Therefore, the class **product** has a lot of properties, the user in the CMS can fill, like this;

```
{
  "title": "Handbrause rot",
  "price": 500,
  "description": "Hello World",
  ...
}
```

and many more. In my Application, I want to normalize the object properties, because I dont need them all:

```
  const normalizedProducts = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < allProducts.length; i++) {
    const normalizedProduct = {
      productId: allProducts[i].id,
      slug: allProducts[i].slug,
      productType: allProducts[i].product_type,
      title: allProducts[i].title,
      description: allProducts[i].description,
      teaser_image: allProducts[i].teaser_image,
      images: allProducts[i].images,
      new: allProducts[i].new,
      topseller: allProducts[i].topseller,
      brand: allProducts[i].brand
    }
    normalizedProducts.push(normalizedProduct);
    return normalizedProducts;
  }
```

The problem now is, that in the API, a lot of times empty fields are returning `undefined`. That results in the problem, that if one property is undefined, that the whole program crashes with e.g. `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'allProducts[i].brand]')`.

Of course, for every property I could write an if-clause or some try catch and the program would not crash. But is there an cleaner way to solve this problem?

**Example data:**

```
[
  {
    productId: 1,
    slug: 'One',
    productType: 'Two',
    title: undefined,
    description: 'Three',
    teaser_image: 'Four',
    images: 'Five',
    new: undefined,
    topseller: undefined,
    brand: undefined,
  },
]
```

Comment: You can do chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

Given a data structure like this:

```
[
  {
    productId: '',
    slug: '',
    productType: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    teaser_image: '',
    images: '',
    new: '',
    topseller: '',
    brand: '',
  },
  undefined
]
```

You can use some of the array methods (.filter and .map) to generate a new normalised array.

```
const normalizedProducts = allProducts
  .filter(product => product) // if product is falsey (false, null, undefined, 0) it will be filtered out
  .map(product => ({
    productId: product.id,
    slug: product.slug,
    productType: product.product_type,
    title: product.title,
    description: product.description,
    teaser_image: product.teaser_image,
    images: product.images,
    new: product.new,
    topseller: product.topseller,
    brand: product.brand,
  }))
```

This should give you the desired result.

[Try it.](https://jsfiddle.net/8aLtywqv/)

Update:

If you have undefined values within a product object and you want to filter those out, it can be done by converting the object to an array, filtering and then converting it back into an object. This uses the `Object.fromEntries()` method which is part of the ES8 spec.

```
// data
const allProducts = [
  {
    productId: 1,
    slug: 'One',
    productType: 'Two',
    title: undefined,
    description: 'Three',
    teaser_image: 'Four',
    images: 'Five',
    new: undefined,
    topseller: undefined,
    brand: undefined,
  },
]

// handler
const dataWithoutUndefined = allProducts.map(product => {
  const filteredData = Object.entries(product).filter(([key, value]) => value)
  return Object.fromEntries(filteredData)
})
```

[Docs for array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Docs for Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your answer, as it seems like a good method. But in my example, the given data would be e.g. `"brand": undefined`. Would this method still work?

Comment: Sorry, that my question was not clear enough. I tested it, and it still prints an error, if one property like "brand" is undefined. I edited my question with example data!

Comment: I've added a link to a fiddle showing it working. There must be something else at play in your code. Do you run anything like `brand.toLoweraCase()` or similar?

Comment: @Cenasa I've updated the answer the the fiddle to cope with undefined values in the product data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use map and reduce methods, declare the properties names in separate array then map your `allProducts` and return the object mapped after checking if its property exists in the original array object:

```
let fields=["productId","slug","productType","title","description","teaser_image",
    "images","new","topseller","brand"]
return allProducts.map(prod=>{
   return fields.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
      if(prod[curr]){//check if prod has that field
         acc[curr]=prod[curr];
       }
    return acc;
  },{})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map your products array then add a function that check if the property is valid :

```
            allProducts = [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "Handbrause rot",
                price: 500,
                description: null,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "Javascritp",
                price: 1000,
                description: "Hello World2",
            },
            ];

            function replaceIfInvalid(data, replacementValue) {
            const isValid = _isValidData(data);
            return isValid ? data : replacementValue;
            }

            function _isValidData(data) {
            return data === null || typeof data === "undefined" ? false : true;
            }

            const normalizedProducts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < allProducts.length; i++) {
            const normalizedProduct = {
                productId: replaceIfInvalid(allProducts[i].id, "-"),
                title: replaceIfInvalid(allProducts[i].title, "-"),
                description: replaceIfInvalid(allProducts[i].description, "-"),
                price: replaceIfInvalid(allProducts[i].price, "$$"),
                 };
                normalizedProducts.push(normalizedProduct);
                console.log(normalizedProducts);
              }
```